# Count items in a dimension according to condition in another dimension

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm working with two dimensions: `Products` and `Colors`

For example, to return all products which are associated to RED color I can write:

```
SELECT {Measures.[Product Count]} ON COLUMNS,
     {[Products].[ID].Members} ON ROWS

FROM MyCube
WHERE [Colors].[Type].&[RED]
```

This will return Products associated to RED color, no matter they are associated to other color too.

Now, I'd like to count those products associated ONLY to RED color. For example, if product is associated to BLUE and RED it shouldn't be counted. The snippet above will not work indeed.

The logical condition is like:

**count products which are exclusively associated to red color**

Can anyone show the right MDX for that?

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to count the number of products that are associated with colors other than red:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[only red] AS
    Count([Products].[ID].Members) -
    Count(NonEmpty([Products].[ID].Members, 
                   CrossJoin(Except([Colors].[Type].Members, {[Colors].[Type].&[RED]}), 
                             {[Measures].[Product Count]})))

SELECT [Measures].[only red] ON 0
FROM MyCube
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've not been able to test it. I'll provide a feedback as soon as possible.